# Copy a File From Resources to Temp Folder

Tags: vb.net, file

I'm making a VB application and I want to copy a file called "L3nEncrypt.jar" which is in *resources* of the application to the *temp folder*.

Right now I have this:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
```

which returns the temp folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution

```
Imports System.IO
File.WriteAllBytes(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp & "/L3nEncrypt.jar", My.Resources.L3nEncrypt)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFileName,DestinationFileName)`

The parameters are full file names of type `string`. Make sure that you're running the application with admin privileges so that the copying can be successful.

Comment: This didn't work it throws ArgumentNullException but I found the solution!Thanks anyways